# Фильтр слов удаляет сообщение с картинкой discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, бот, фильтрация

Недавно я написал фильтр слов, которые удаляет сообщения, в которых есть слова из массива "banword". Сам код свою задачу выполняет довольно хорошо. Но при двухдневном тесте выявилась проблема: если к сообщению приложить картинку, то бот заблокирует это сообщение.
Как исправить?
Вот код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
 text = message.content
 intext = text.split(" ")
 words = len(intext)
 banwords = ["всякие", "нехорошие", "и", "матные", "слова"]
 banwordslist = len(banwords)
 checked = 0
 wordcheck = 0
 banword = 0
 ban = 0
 while checked != words:
  if banword != banwordslist:
   bw = banwords[banword]
   ww = intext[wordcheck]
   if bw.lower() in ww.lower():
    ban = ban + 1
    banword = banword + 1
   if bw.lower() not in ww.lower():
    banword = banword + 1
  else:
   banword = 0
   wordcheck = wordcheck + 1
   checked = checked + 1
 if ban >= 1:
  user = message.author.id()
  await message.delete()
  await message.channel.send("<@{0}> , не лучшее место для мата.".format(user))
```

Comment: а какое там название картинки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В коде есть пара моментов, которые стоит исправить:**

- `user = message.author.id()`, здесь вы пытаетесь получить `id` пользователя, вызывая его свойство как функцию. Но `id` - это не функция, а просто переменная класса (свойство), если проще. **Поэтому правильно будет получать `id` вот так:** *(Иначе вы получите ошибку)*

```
user = message.author.id
```

- `await message.delete()` удаление сообщения лучше обернуть в конструкцию исключения ошибки. Так как, если кто-то напишет боту в личные сообщения, бот не сможет удалить сообщение из-за отсутствия прав и вы получите ошибку.

```
try:
   await message.delete()
except:
   pass
```

- **Ну и просто подмечу:** Упоминание не обязательно форматировать таким сложным способом `'<@{0}>'.format(message.author.id)`, можно просто использовать встроенное свойство объекта `user` - `mention`

```
await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, не лучшее место для мата.')
```

---

Далее, хотелось бы добавить, что у вас какой-то очень замороченный код :)

Такой фильтр можно написать гораздо проще, и, как мне кажется, он будет работать стабильнее.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: return # если сообщение от бота - игнорируем
    banwords = ["всякие", "нехорошие", "и", "матные", "слова"]
    for word in banwords:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            try:
                await message.delete()
            except:
                pass
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, не лучшее место для мата')
            break
```

При получении сообщения, если оно не от бота, проверяем в цикле наличие каждого слова в тексте сообщения. Если хоть одно слово попадается, то цикл прерывается (`break`) и выполняется удаление сообщения с отправкой текста *"не лучшее место для мата"*

---

**Если вам нужно подсчитать кол-во запрещенных слов в тексте - можно использовать встроенную функцию строки `count()`**. Например, можно подсчитать количество единиц в строке:

```
text = '1112233133456'
count = text.count('1') # 4
```

---

Что же насчет отправки картинок - ни в вашем коде, ни в моем, я не нашел никаких проблем с блокировкой изображений. Даже пробовал называть их словами из списка - ничего не происходит.

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало без проблем и ошибок. denisnumb, Вы лучший :)