# Привет! Discord.py event. Как мне выдавать мут человеку который использовал в сообщение слово из links_words и его замутить роль config.MutedRole

Tags: python, события, discord.py

```
gif_word = ['.gif']
tenor_com = ['tenor.com']

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
   for word3 in tenor_com:
       if word3 in msg.content:
           return
       else:
           for word in likns_words:
               if word in msg.content:
                       if msg.author == bot.user:
                            pass
                       else:
                           for word2 in gif_word:
                               if word2 in msg.content:
                                   pass
                               else:
                                   await msg.delete()
                                   print(discord.author.name, 'using likns_words')
                                   await discord.author.name.add_roles(config.MutedRole)
                                   
   await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Comment: Уже были подобные вопросы, просто вместо запрещенных слов в списке укажите ваши ссылки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1292308/373173, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1341325/373173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код, без использования гиф, он работать, если в `config.MutedRole` вы получили объект роли, а в `links_words` все запретные слова написаны без использования больших букв.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in links_words:
        member = message.author
        member.add_roles(config.MutedRole)
```

Comment: нет. Мне нужно чтобы сообщение удалялось + чтобы бот не удалял свои сообещения с сылкой

Comment: проще говоря я просто искал message.author

Comment: Чтобы удалить сообщение именно с запретным словом, используйте ```await message.delete()```